# JS overlay without direct access to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, overlay

I am attempting to add a javascript overlay onload, without direct access to the html. I'm only able to upload .js and .css files.

How would I go about doing this, I've searched all over, but as I am no expert at this I'm seeking a simple solution which will allow me to maybe call html and insert it into an overlay, by using **javascript only**.

I am unsure of the coding of the .js file to contain all of the overlay code and html code combined.

I've been looking at document.getElementById and document.write to do this, am I correct in trying to do it this way?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the existing html contain a link <script src="yourfile.js"> to the file you are going to upload? If not I don't see how this could be achieved.

Comment: Yes I can add a link, but that't about it, I cannot add anything else. This is what I'm unsure about, the coding.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can add an overlay to an existing html file without importing the new JS and CSS files in the html file. How ever, if there are other JS files used or imported to the HTML file, edit it and add your code in the JS file. It'll run since the JS file is already imported in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain clear enough, what I meant was.. I can add a .js file to the html, however I cannot access the html file directly or add any coding but a link to a .js or .css file.